# How to calculate sum of one column and append it in a row via Talend

Tags: talend

I have a Talend [Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvrM9.png) , i have an csv file in input and output, i want to calculate the sum of a column and append it in a the row csv output, how can i do that ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: try to use a tAggregate component to do the staff , there is already a sum function in it

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa Hello Amine, thanks for your response, the issue with tAggregate is that it change the actual column, i want to keep the same structure but just add the sum in one particular celll !

Comment: use tjavarow take a context variable or global variable and add new value everytime row passes through, i can explain further if needed.